# How to manage txt files in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, symfony-3.3

I want to create a txt file from an action in a controller to store some data in it then delete it when I am done with it. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Filesystem component: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html

You can use dumpFile or appendToFile methods to write in the file and remove method to remove the file.

Comment: thanks. but how can i create the file in the first place? from what i know mkdir only create directories?

Comment: accoring to the link given: `$fs->dumpFile('file.txt', 'Hello World');`